# Is it possible to run a groovy grails application on aws lambda

Tags: grails, groovy, aws-lambda

I have a simple groovy grails Web application that I can run on my local machine through grails-> run-app command line and access the web application (view page on gsp) on localhost using the browser. Is is possible to run/migrate the same application onto AWS Lambda, so that I can create an API gateway for this and hit the application from a browser.

I am able to use gradle build to make the .zip file. Below is the main function runs the grails application. The application has the regular grails MVC structure.

```
import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

What should be the handler function for AWS lambda in order to run the application serverless, if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: grails starts application server, and aws-lambda is a serverless technology. so answer is - no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is is possible to run/migrate the same application onto AWS Lambda, so
>   that I can create an API gateway for this and hit the application from
>   a browser.

No, but you can deploy the app to AWS so you can hit the application from a browser.  One option is to use AWS Beanstalk.  See https://guides.grails.org/grails-elasticbeanstalk/guide/index.html.